# Rails Asset Caching Breaks First few page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, assets

We're using Rails asset caching for JS and CSS like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'reset','global','admins','autocomplete', 'date_input', 'tablesorter', 'partners', 'jqmodal', :media => 'screen', :cache => set_asset_cache(:admins) %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'autocomplete', 'searchbox', 'jqmodal', :cache => set_asset_cache(:admins) %>
```

In our deploy we call `rake tmp:assets:clear` each time.  The problem is that the first few page loads after a deploy come up with no css or js on the page.  I guess until the cached all.js and all.css have been regenerated.

We deploy many times per day and this is scary for any users who happen to come across a busted page.

Have people found any way to make this smoother so the new cached assets are guaranteed to be there on the first new page load?

Comment: A few questions:
1) Do you have multiple app servers on different machines?
2) What is the cache line for the CSS in the templates?

Comment: Hi Scott.  All app servers on one machine.  Here is an example of the css cache line: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'reset','global','admins','autocomplete', 'date_input', 'tablesorter', 'partners', 'jqmodal', :media => 'screen', :cache => set_asset_cache(:admins) %>`  We have separate ones for admins, buyers, sellers, landing pages, etc (one per layout).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AssetHat](https://github.com/mintdigital/asset_hat/) gem addresses this exact problem. Instead of concatenating assets the first time a page is loaded (which increases that page's load time), it concatenates assets on deploy instead. As a bonus, the gem also minifies your CSS and JS, which saves precious bytes.

After setup, usage is pretty simple:

- Use `include_css :bundle => 'admins'` and `include_js :bundle => 'admins'` in your layout. (The bundle contents are set in a config file to keep your layout lightweight.)
- Add `rake asset_hat:minify` to your deploy script. My company has been using it in production with Capistrano for about a year now.

There's more info in the [readme](https://github.com/mintdigital/asset_hat/#readme) and [docs](http://mintdigital.github.com/asset_hat/doc/), and I'd be happy to hear any questions/ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You could try warming the cache during deployment using wget, as an example ([shamelessly reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543961/warm-up-cache-on-deployment/543988#543988)):

```
wget -r -nd --delete-after http://whatever.com/~popular/page/
```

However, this would have to be executed after you switch your symlink to your new deployment. A possibly more elegant solution might be to call the asset caching methods manually in your deploy, though I'm not sure how feasible that is. [Here's where the caching is performed in Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html):

```
# File vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb, line       273
273:       def javascript_include_tag(*sources)
274:         options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys
275:         concat  = options.delete("concat")
276:         cache   = concat || options.delete("cache")
277:         recursive = options.delete("recursive")
278: 
279:         if concat || (ActionController::Base.perform_caching && cache)
280:           joined_javascript_name = (cache == true ? "all" : cache) + ".js"
281:           joined_javascript_path = File.join(joined_javascript_name[/^#{File::SEPARATOR}/] ? ASSETS_DIR : JAVASCRIPTS_DIR, joined_javascript_name)
282: 
283:           unless ActionController::Base.perform_caching && File.exists?(joined_javascript_path)
284:             write_asset_file_contents(joined_javascript_path, compute_javascript_paths(sources, recursive))
285:           end
286:           javascript_src_tag(joined_javascript_name, options)
287:         else
288:           expand_javascript_sources(sources, recursive).collect { |source| javascript_src_tag(source, options) }.join("\n")
289:         end
290:       end
```

You might be able to modify the caching code and run it manually on deploy.

Comment: The wget could work, although some of our assets caches only get generated on logged in pages (one for admins, buyers, sellers, etc) so I don't think a use can login with a simple wget.  The write_asset_file_contents method looks promising.  If someone has that working from a capistrano deploy that would be interesting.